# Unexpected exception after update to vaadin 8

Tags: java, vaadin8

I'm getting the below error on the ListSelect component. A few version back in vaadin 8 it's working file. Now I've updated the version to 8.14.2 then I'm getting this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client tried fetch more rows than allowed. This is denied to prevent denial of service.
    at com.vaadin.data.provider.DataCommunicator.onRequestRows(DataCommunicator.java:311)
    at com.vaadin.data.provider.DataCommunicator$SimpleDataRequestRpc.requestRows(DataCommunicator.java:74)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor370.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The default is 500. You can increase this by calling `setMaximumAllowedRows` on your `DataCommunicator`.

Comment: Could you describe under which circumstances you need to have more than 500 rows lazy loaded at once to a Grid or ComboBox?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But there is no such method ("setMaximumAllowedRows ") in DataCommunicator as I see

Comment: DataCommunicator#setMaximumAllowedRows is coming in next release, you can use it with 8.15-SNAPSHOT already. Jut noting ListSelect, TwinColSelect, ... do not have lazy loading support at all, and not purposed for large data sets.

Comment: Thanks, @TatuLund. I see version 8.15-SNAPSHOT is not available in the central maven repository

Comment: Vaadin snapshots and other prereleases are not published in maven central, you need to add vaadin prereleases repo https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/

Comment: Seems to have been been introduced in 8.14.x our users just reported it today after we did an upgrade from 8.13.x to 8.14.1 last week

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug on 8.14.x version when scrolling grid
with grid scroll element and grid has lazy data provider and a lot available hieght. Grid client element fetchs more than 500 rows. If I minimize grid no exception thrown. [Exception img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qmzc.png)

Comment: when i use a Grid with more than 500 items i dont get this error. But with ListSelect and over 500 items i get this error.

Comment: I've noticed `TwinColSelect` is buggy on 8.14.3 too.